# CloudPages - AMPscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage

We have a custom built Preference Center using CloudPages. We have recently asked a partner to place our CloudPage Preference Center on to their site for subscribers to sign-up on, so it will be a blank/evergreen Preference Center. This is the only place a blank/evergreen Preference Center would exist. The only other way subscribers can access is via the 'Update Preferences' button in an email, which would have their email, name, etc. pre-populated.

I want to track 'source' as a URL parameter from the landing page that is on the partner site. For example, the preference center URL (landing page) on the partner site is this `www.landingpage.com?source=example.com`

On my processing page, I have the following:

```
Set @source = RequestParameter('source')
UpsertData("Subscribers_Example", 1, "email", @email, "FirstName", @firstname, "LastName", @lastname, "Source", @source )
```

Source is not being populated though. I really can't set a hidden field on the landing page because I only want this to happen on a new/blank Preference Sign-up, and if I did a hidden field it would update that source field on existing subscribers preferences when they went to update.

How can I make this work?